# PostGIS 1.5 Error with PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: postgis, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to add PostGIS functionality to a database that I created in PostgreSQL using the following command: `psql -d <db_name> -f /location/to/this/file/postgis.sql`

However, I receive a bunch of errors relating to 'geometry does not exist', but on line 1 of these error messages, it says `ERROR: could not access file “$libdir/postgis-1.5”`.

I Google'd and checked StackOverflow, and it seems like this error is related to dependencies or scripts not being installed. I installed PostGIS using `yum install postgis84`. I did not see any dependencies except for `proj`. Based on [these instructions](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_requirements), it seems like I will need Proj4, GEOS, LibXML2, GDAL, JSON-C, etc.

Is there a repository that I can connect to that will let me install PostGIS with all the crucial dependencies rather than installing them one by one? I am running a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 server on Amazon EC2.

I am new to databases, so please excuse me if I used any incorrect lingo.

Comment: X-post to http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/125218/12379

Comment: Is there any reason you are using an outdated Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am transferring a database from one server to another (EC2). My current database is Postgres 8.4.2. I would like to jump to 9.x eventually. I just wasn't sure if right now it would be appropriate as it may result in errors or incompatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I found the RPM's for GDAL, GEOS, and Proj4. They are located here: http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/

Since they are not packaged with PostgreSQL 8.4, you have to install them one by one. I hope this helps someone in future.